# Clearing the Console in BASIC

Tags: console, basic

I've tried researching for the answer but nothing comes up.

The results it showed me would say to put 'clear' or 'clr' in the code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try CLS, short for clear screen.  Clear and clr are meant for memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
PRINT CHR$(147)
```

should clear the screen (tested on a C64c)